# Resizing game dimensions for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, bitmap

I have created an game based on 480x320p and when I tested it on 1280x800p tablet it was working well, except the bitmaps for my game resources weren't updating well.

First of all this is how the issue looks on Nexus 5: 1080x1920 pixels (~445 ppi pixel density)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0u8kyWNwqykZlNIRVBpVEFPZ00/view?usp=sharing

This is how it should look (Nexus 1: 480×800p)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0u8kyWNwqykalNiUExuSzNNelU/view?usp=sharing

This is the XML code I have for the main game layout and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_game_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

as you can see it is relative layout that should match the screen size.
Then I assign layout in Game.java

```
 RelativeLayout Rel_main_game
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        Rel_main_game = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_game_rl);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        final int heightS = dm.heightPixels;
        final int widthS = dm.widthPixels;
```

Then I set the @drawable/background in the game panel and it does not fill the screen properly.

```
background = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.game_background), ScreenWidth, this);
```

Q1:How can I update my @drawable/nodpi resources and also layouts so that they will adapt to the different screen sizes and screen ratios?
Q2:Another minor issue I have that sound resources continue to play after I leave the app. I am sure if you can fix Q1 this will not be an issue :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try fill_parent instead of match_parent? just to clear it up

Comment: didn't do a thing @amitfarag. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

you can set to full screen like so:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: I have had it like that but the resources do not update with it.